# Array length checking speed

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm away from my PC else I would have given this a go:

Suppose we have an array of arbitrary length (say, 5) each index storing numbers from 1 to 5 in ascending order (i.e int[0] = 1, etc).

Then suppose we take an input from the user, an array of variable length, storing variable integers. I want to verify that the two arrays are identical.

Is it at all faster for me, to take the preliminary check of are these arrays the same length, and then check the actual values if they are, or set up some iterative loop system that iterates through both arrays and verifies if they're identical? Is the array length just some stored variable in the actual structure? I mean, the speed difference will be minute, I was just wondering. Using javascript at the moment.

But my thinking in general is, if the array length is a variable, then it's better to access that first and just compare, if not its better to iterate through as an array.length operation would still iterate through the array to count the numbers?

If only I had the documentation with me.

Comment: In order to iterate through *both* arrays, you're going to need to know the lesser of their lengths regardless (otherwise when would the iteration stop?), so you may as well use that opportunity to compare their lengths.

Comment: You can verify string identicals: array1.join()===array2.join()

Comment: Of course you should check the length in advance. You think it might not be more efficient, or no less efficient, to do that, instead of checking 1000 elements before suddenly noticing that one array was shorter?

Comment: I think the length is stored in a variable. Otherwise checking lengths would be a very expensive operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clarify my comment: suppose for some reason you want to implement the comparison without checking their lengths.  Okay, so that means we need to iterate through the elements and check if they are equal, sounds simple right?  This is how it would look like (using Python here for clarity, but this is mostly independent of language):

```py
def equal(arrayA, arrayB):
    for i in range(0, ???):
       if arrayA[i] != arrayB[i]:
           return False
    return True
```

But here's the catch, when does the iteration stop?  (What goes in the `???` part?)  Well, you have to stop before you run out of elements, and that occurs whenever you reach `min(len(arrayA), len(arrayB))`.

Alas, a typical `min` function would be implemented as thus:

```py
def min(x, y):
    if x < y:
        return x
    else:
        return y
```

which means you're going to need to do a comparison `<`.  Well if you have to do a comparison, *you may as well just do an equality comparison of the lengths* since that's about the same cost on most architectures.

So the conclusion is: you can't avoid doing a comparison between the lengths of the arrays, so you may as well use that opportunity to check if they are equal.

Comment: Is this python? If so please specify it in your answer so that it doesn't confuse anyone (because the question is tagged as JavaScript)

Comment: It was originally a language-agnostic question, but I'll mention that.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure whether to tag it as javascript or not originally. S'alright, I can read python.